# set all executable files executable by all users but leave un-executable file non-executable?

Tags: permissions, acl, umask

I have a directory owned by root, after I copy files into it. All exe files can only be run as root. But I would like everyone to be able to run it.
Surely, I can use `chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX` every time after I add new files into it. However, this is very annoying. Is there any thing I can set in the directory to automatically allow all users to run the exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `umask 0022` before making the copy, you will get all new files with `-rw-r--r--` permissions by default, but files can be made executable only invoking directly chmod +x on them.

You can use the abbreviated command: `chmod -R a+rX directory` to do it manually.

To automatically set all file permissions you can use inotifywait like that:

```
inotifywait -qm <directory> -e create -e moved_to -e modify \
 | while read a b c; do chmod a+rX "${a}${c}"; done
```

Comment: alternative abbreviation: `chmod a+rX`.  according to taste

Comment: I've lost a piece of info in the topic, I've corrected the answer thanks to @sourcejedi